# Why isn't my if, elseif, else statement working?

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

I'm working on a Mad Libs type assignment. I'm trying to have the heroname dictate the name of the frog my professor is making me use in the story, but for some reason, my if statement to rename the frog isn't working.

Every time I try to enter names for heroname (when it asks for "your name", it always ends up defaulting to Taylor and putting Henry as the frogname. How can I make this if-else statement work correctly to make the name be Henry only if Taylor or Jamie are entered for the heroname?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Mad Libs Time</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>MAD LIBS TIME, HOMIE!</h1>
<p>Y'arr, this be a tale all about the lives of ye and yer pirate mateys. Full of adventure, loss, love, and magic this story be. In order to tell it to ye the way ya like, answer a few questions before I throw ye in the brig!</p>
<form name="gatheringinfo" method="post" action="tellthatstory.php">
Aye, what's yer name? <input type="text" name="heroname"><br/>
What be yer best matey's name? <input type="text" name="friendname"><br/>
Name the wizard of this tale: <input type="text" name="wizardname"><br/>
What be the wizard's power?<select name="power">
    <option value="fire">Fire</option>
    <option value="earth">Earth</option>
    <option value="water">Water</option>
</select><br/>
Pick a number, 1 to 10..<select name="pickanumber">
    <option value="one">1</option>
    <option value="two">2</option>
    <option value="three">3</option>
    <option value="four">4</option>
    <option value="five">5</option>
    <option value="six">6</option>
    <option value="seven">7</option>
    <option value="eight">8</option>
    <option value="nine">9</option>
    <option value="ten">10</option>
</select><br/>
And lastly, before we get started, pick ye weapon...<select name="weapon">
    <option value="scimitar">Scimitar</option>
    <option value="musket">Musket</option>
    <option value="dagger">Dagger</option>
</select><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Spin Me A Tale"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php

$heroname=$_POST['heroname'];
$friendname=$_POST['friendname'];
$wizardname=$_POST['wizardname'];
$power=$_POST['power'];
$pickanumber=$_POST['pickanumber'];
$weapon=$_POST['weapon'];

switch ($power) {
case "fire":
    $power="Fire";
    $fight_sentence=2;
    break;
case "earth":
    $power="Earth";
    $fight_sentence=4;
    break;
case "water":
    $power="Water";
    $fight_sentence=6;
    break;
}

$frogstory = array("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "");

switch ($pickanumber) {
case "one":
    $reasonforfrog="frogstory[0]";
    break;
case "two":
    $reasonforfrog="frogstory[1]";
    break;
case "three":
    $reasonforfrog="frogstory[2]";
    break;
case "four":
    $reasonforfrog="frogstory[3]";
    break;
case "five":
    $reasonforfrog="frogstory[4]";
    break;
case "six":
    $reasonforfrog="frogstory[5]";
    break;
case "seven":
    $reasonforfrog="frogstory[6]";
    break;
case "eight":
    $reasonforfrog="frogstory[7]";
    break;
case "nine":
    $reasonforfrog="frogstory[8]";
    break;
case "ten":
    $reasonforfrog="frogstory[9]";
    break;
}    

switch ($weapon) {
case "scimitar":
    $weapon="scimitar";
    break;
case "musket":
    $weapon="musket";
    break;
case "dagger":
    $weapon="dagger";
    break;
}

if($heroname="Taylor"):
$frogname="Henry";
elseif($heroname="taylor"):
$frogname="Henry";
elseif($heroname="Jamie"):
$frogname="Henry";
elseif($heroname="jamie"):
$frogname="Henry";
else: $frogname="Matthew";
endif;

echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;The day the fearless pirate $heroname and the fearless friend $friendname took their first step offshore, they never knew the adventures the future would hold for them both. They plundered and pillaged for years and years, always getting their fill of the booty and rum that flowed effortlessly into their lives. Just as they were getting used to all of the excitement.. just as they were about to cash out.. just as they were about to transfer back to life on land.. they were approached by their superior, Captain Rumbeard.<br/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;He told $heroname and $friendname that he was visited by the wizard $wizardname in a dream and was told where the biggest treasure trove he'd ever heard of lied in wait. $frogname";
?>
```

Comment: Because this is not how php if statement looks... http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_if_else.asp

Comment: @sashkello you are mistaken, it is valid: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php
and please don't reference w3schools :(

Comment: its == not = for comparison

Comment: @zamnuts 1. Wow! Didn't know that... Bad practice though IMO. 2. why not? It's the first link in PHP if else and does give an idea...

Comment: @sashkello 1. it is not bad practice, syntax is completely valid and in some cases is safer than leaving a trailing curly brace (that could wreak havoc if parts of the statement are removed), 2. http://www.w3fools.com/ ...use the source http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php

Comment: @zamnuts 1. Still disagree, but matter of taste. 2. OK, I see, valid point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing assignment instead of comparison. Change `if($heroname="Taylor"):` to `if($heroname=="Taylor"):` (i.e. `=` should be `==`).

(Note: You need to fix that in *all four* conditions, not just the first one.)

Answer (score 1):

You're using the assignment operator (=) not the comparison operator(==/===)

```
if($heroname="Taylor"):
$frogname="Henry";
elseif($heroname="taylor"):
$frogname="Henry";
elseif($heroname="Jamie"):
$frogname="Henry";
elseif($heroname="jamie"):
$frogname="Henry";
else: $frogname="Matthew";
endif;
```

to

```
if($heroname == "Taylor")
    $frogname = "Henry";
elseif($heroname == "taylor")
    $frogname = "Henry";
elseif($heroname == "Jamie")
    $frogname = "Henry";
elseif($heroname == "jamie")
    $frogname = "Henry";
else
    $frogname = "Matthew";
```

Even better:

```
switch($heroname){
    case 'Taylor':
    case 'taylor':
    case 'Jamie':
    case 'jamie':
        $frogname = 'Henry';
        break;
    default:
        $frogname = 'Matthew';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something practical. Try it this way:

```
if (in_array(strtolower($heroname), array("taylor", "jamie"))) $frogname="Henry";
else $frogname=="Matthew";
```